# Squeaking / Chirping while pedaling

Tags: bottom-bracket, noise

I have a [2009 Specialized Allez Sport C2](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2009&brand=Specialized&model=Allez+Sport+C2).

When pedaling (actually only under load, not when just turning the crank while it's on a stand) the bottom bracket squeaks or chirps. I first thought it was birds chirping;  then I realized they were remarkably regular in their chirping.  Then I realized it was my bike. The sound has definitely gotten worse over time.

What should I be looking at in terms of fixing this?  Do I need to replace the bottom bracket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"squeaks" can come from a lot of places in the bike - they're transmitted surprisingly well - which helps them escape detection.

If it corresponds with pedal strokes, then you're probably looking at the following:

- bottom bracket - regrease and tighten to spec
- pedals - regrease and tighten to spec
- cleats - tighten to spec

It's a process of elimination - e.g. see if it happens when you're only putting down power with one foot. Or see if it happens only when standing.

If it's not all the time, but only when you're standing, then it could be something in your steering (i.e. change in body position makes it worse).